# Poner publicidad entre cierta cantidad de parrafos

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-adsense

Hola gente estoy intentando integrar `adsense` entre los `párrafos` de mis posts, el tema es que yo uso el editor `CKEditor`, ese editor hace que todo el contenido se guarde con formato `html`, entonces lo que yo solo hago con `php` es llamar la columna de la tabla donde se encuentra toda la redacción de la nota.

```
<?php echo $post->descripcion;?>
```

entonces por ejemplo al mostrar en la pagina web se muestra de esta forma en html

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut eum atque reiciendis, a suscipit omnis magni quae mollitia facilis! Laudantium dolorem distinctio, fugiat ipsa facere illo perferendis officia doloremque voluptate.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut eum atque reiciendis, a suscipit omnis magni quae mollitia facilis! Laudantium dolorem distinctio, fugiat ipsa facere illo perferendis officia doloremque voluptate.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut eum atque reiciendis, a suscipit omnis magni quae mollitia facilis! Laudantium dolorem distinctio, fugiat ipsa facere illo perferendis officia doloremque voluptate.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut eum atque reiciendis, a suscipit omnis magni quae mollitia facilis! Laudantium dolorem distinctio, fugiat ipsa facere illo perferendis officia doloremque voluptate.</p>
```

busque en internet de como integrar adsense entre párrafos pero todos son para wordpress, vale aclarar que yo **no uso wordpress**

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con esto se los agradecería mucho!

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo el [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos explicando concretamente tu pregunta. Esto y otras cosas más que encontrarás en el link que te cité, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con php puedes dividir el contenido de la descripción del post (utilizando la función explode) de acuerdo a cierto criterio (yo en este caso utilicé "\n" nueva línea, pero de acuerdo a como esté estructurado el mismo tendrás que elegir el delimitador que mas te convenga), luego recorrer dicho contenido (almacenado en el arreglo $parrafos), concatenar el mismo en una nueva variable ($htmlPostDescripcion) intercalando el código de los anuncios adsense.

```
<?php
$htmlPostDescripcion = "";
$parrafos = explode("\n", $post->descripcion);
$contador = 0;

foreach($parrafos as $parrafo) {
    if(strlen(trim($parrafo)) > 0) {
        $contador++;
        $htmlPostDescripcion .= $parrafo;

        if(($contador % 4) == 0) {
            $htmlPostDescripcion .= "colcar código hmtl de los anuncios aquí";
        }
    }
}

echo $htmlPostDescripcion;
?>
```

Al dividir el contenido utilizando "\n" en mi caso obtengo elementos que son una cadena vacia, por eso chequeo `if(strlen(trim($parrafo)) > 0)` dentro del foreach.

También podrías hacer algo similar en MySQL utilizando expresiones regulares, pero creo que utilizando php tendrás mas flexibilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, acabo de probar tu solución y si me muestra el bloque de anuncio entre párrafos, pero el problema es que me muestra en cada corte de párrafo, cual seria la manera de delimitar la cantidad de párrafos y que ahí recién aparezcan? un ejemplo `4 párrafos, anuncio, 4 párrafos otro anuncio`, se podrá amoldar a eso tu código? desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada @Daniel, podrías utilizar una variable contador que se incremente en cada iteración, y cuando llegue a un valor múltiplo de 4 en este caso (`if(($contador % 4) == 0)`) concatenas el anuncio.

Comment: muchísimas gracias por tu solución, te lo agradezco un montón!

Comment: De nada @Daniel! Me alegra haberte ayudado.